# CSV not callable - was working yestereday

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Literally the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def rtst():
    CSVfile = pd.read_csv('csvfilename.csv')
    return  CSVfile
read()
```

Returns the following error "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

I swear this same code worked yesterday, in the same Jupyter workbook

Comment: change read() to rtst()....

Comment: Blast, I missed that in the rewrite of the code - but it isn't the problem.  It still doesn't work.  I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

The form

```
CSVfile = pd.read_csv('csvfilename.csv')
return CSVfile
```

suddenly started working again.  I've compared it to saved files - there was not other change.